# Detect lock release in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

Here's what I want to do:

```
try to lock a few documents
if any lock fails:
  unlock any docs we've locked so far
  wait until all locks are cleared
  retry from beginning
do something
```

However, I don't know how to efficiently wait until all locks are cleared. I can't find anything in the couchbase docs, other than using an "infinite" loop that checks if the lock attempt returns a temporary failure error. Is there any good way to wait the correct amount of time before retrying? (plus some random time to avoid repeated conflicts)

Waiting 15+ seconds before retrying isn't really that user-friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not directly.

Two possible optimizations could make it a bit more efficient though.

One is that you could, at the app level, have a scheme whereby if you can't acquire the lock you maintain a record with waiters on that lock so only the topmost one or two are trying to acquire the lock.

Two is that you probably should use an exponential backoff retry to efficiently retry on the lock.  If you really want to get sophisticated, you could build and train a model around a negative exponential on when the lock is most likely available.  This is where you'd poll more frequently as the "deadline" approaches and the math for that is described with a negative exponential function.

Comment: If multiple servers are competing to lock some docs, and they both fail, it's a really bad idea to use exponentially decreasing waiting time. If both try again at the same time, we get the same problem over and over again.

Comment: Except they'll never be at exactly the same time if they're locking in the same order.  One will succeed and the others will have to wait.

Comment: Yes, but if they don't lock in the same order. They could lock "many" documents each, with only a few documents being locked by both threads. They don't have to do the same task when they're locking the same documents.

Comment: Indeed, if you can't use the same order it gets much more complicated.  The lock with a timeout in Couchbase won't solve this for you.  There are many good publications on things like deadlock detection and backoff for such situations that apply here.  In general, most people try to refactor the problem to avoid such complexity.  It's frequently, but not always possible.

Comment: I'm guessing locking the keys in lexicographical order would solve it.